# Prevent Background Scroll on Modal Box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a plugin which has a modal pop up box for login (CM Registration Pro). I would like the background (body of my website) to not be able to scroll when the modal pop up is open.
I have tried the following code but am unable to get it to work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
if($('.cmreg-overlay').length){
    $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
} 
});
```

If you would like to see the problem live my website is **[Redec](http://s2br5s5r3.gb-02.live-paas.net/)**

Comment: You should set `background-attachment:fixed` rather than `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: @WaisKamal I just tried `$('html').css('background-attachment', 'fixed');` but it doesn't work

Comment: Can we see your HTML?

Comment: @WaisKamal I am unable to access my html as I am using wordpress to build my website, I can access css

Comment: Ok, can you share the link for your website? And btw you can always see the HTML in the browser dev tools.

Comment: @WaisKamal Here is my website: http://s2br5s5r3.gb-02.live-paas.net/

Comment: Well, see if my answer helps.

Comment: @WaisKamal Do you have any other solutions please?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your body has no background. If you mean you don't want your body to scroll when the modal box is open, then you can check whether `.cmreg-overlay` is shown, and if so then set `overflow:hidden` to the body.

I will assume that only `#menu-item-16137`, `#menu-item-16194` and `#menu-item-16195` are Here is how to do it:

```
// Prevent the body from scrolling when the modal opens
var x = document.querySelectorAll("#menu-item-16137, #menu-item-16194, #menu-item-16195");
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if($(".cmreg-overlay").style.display != none) {
      document.body.style.overflow = hidden;
    }
  });
}

// Return the body back to scrolling when closing the modal
document.querySelector(".cmreg-overlay").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have just tried this and the body still scrolls

`jQuery( function($) {
if($(".cmreg-overlay").style.display != none) {
  document.body.style.overflow = hidden;
}
});`

Comment: It's worth noting that this approach would work but you need to wrap the code inside an event listener e.g. an on click. As it currently is the code only runs an if statement on page load ( which will always be false )

Comment: @AaronMcGuire How could I do this?

Comment: @AaronMcGuire thanks for pointing this out. I will edit my code.

Answer (score 0):

A Quick example that should work is:-

```
var element = document.querySelector('body');
element.addEventListener('click',function(){

if(element.classList.contains('.cmreg-overlay-visible')){
   document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}
else{
   document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'visible';
}
});
```